# Eloquent belongsToMany and Three Tables (Including Pivot)

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, has-and-belongs-to-many

[image]

I am working on an Ecommerce project using the Laravel framework.  I have a products table, a flavors table, and a flavor_product table (I believe this is referred to as a pivot table).  I have a Product model and a Flavor model (from what I have read it is unnecessary to create a model for the pivot table).

In the Product model I have defined the following relationship:

```
public function flavors()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Flavor');
}
```

In the Flavor model I have defined the following relationship:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
}
```

Now, in my Product controller I have attempted the following:

```
$flavors = Product::select('id')->with('flavors')->get();
```

which gets sent to the applicable view (product.blade.php).

In product.blade.php I have the following:

```
@foreach ($flavors as $flavor)
  <select id="product-flavor" class="bs-select">
     <option value="{{ $flavor }}">{{ $flavor }}</option>
  </select>
@endforeach
```

So, what is the giving me?  Well, it's showing me the following:

```
{"id":1,"flavors":[{"id":1,"name":"Cake Batter","created_at":"2018-05-29 20:12:56","updated_at":"2018-05-29 20:12:56","pivot":{"product_id":1,"flavor_id":1}},{"id":2,"name":"Caramel Coffee","created_at":"2018-05-29 20:48:25","updated_at":"2018-05-29 20:48:25","pivot":{"product_id":1,"flavor_id":2}},{"id":3,"name":"Chocolate Milkshake","created_at":"2018-05-29 20:49:09","updated_at":"2018-05-29 20:49:09","pivot":{"product_id":1,"flavor_id":3}},{"id":4,"name":"Cookies &amp; Cream","created_at":"2018-05-29 20:49:50","updated_at":"2018-05-29 20:49:50","pivot":{"product_id":1,"flavor_id":4}},{"id":5,"name":"Vanilla Milkshake","created_at":"2018-05-29 20:50:16","updated_at":"2018-05-29 20:50:16","pivot":{"product_id":1,"flavor_id":5}}]}
```

which I definitely don't want all of that.  All I want is to retrieve the name of the flavors associated to that product via the pivot table.

How can I proceed on this?

### Edit

The following code is in the ShopController.php (regarding how the product is retrieved and displayed):

```
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  string  $slug
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($slug)
{
    $product = Product::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
    $mightAlsoLike = Product::where('slug', '!=', $slug)->mightAlsoLike()->get();

    return view('product')->with([
        'product' => $product,
        'mightAlsoLike' => $mightAlsoLike,
    ]);
}
```

From web.php:

```
Route::get('/shop/{product}', 'ShopController@show')->name('shop.show');
```

Comment: Associated with which product?

Comment: The one that is currently displayed.

Comment: Hmm, can you share the code where you retrieve that product and display it? How do you know which products' flavours you want to retrieve? Right now your code fetches all the products.

Comment: I hope the additional info I've added in my edit is what you're looking for.  The product is retrieved based on the unique slug of the product.

Comment: Yup, that makes it more clear what you want. Will fix you up with the solution.

Comment: Thank you and hopefully I can garner understanding so that I don't make the same mistake in the future.

Comment: `<option value="{{ $flavor }}">{{ $flavor }}</option>` this line.. is not it will print the json of the `flavor` instance? perhaps, try `<option value="{{ $flavor->id }}">{{ $flavor->name }}</option>`..?

Comment: (Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened).

Comment: I'm human, not a computer, but I'll try to be more technical in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing here is telling Laravel to select `id` from all products and retrieve all of their associated flavours.

```
Product::select('id') // <-- Will only select `id` attribute from the `products` table
    ->with('flavors') // <-- Will attach associated flavors to the product id
    ->get(); // <-- End the query (get all product ids and their flavours)
```

In your case, you don't want to select all the products and you have the relation set up correctly. So what you should do is call `->with('flavors')` on your original query (actually not needed in this case, since you won't run into `n+1` problems but still good practice):

```
$product = Product::where('slug', $slug)->with('flavors')->firstOrFail();
$mightAlsoLike = Product::where('slug', '!=', $slug)->mightAlsoLike()->get();

return view('product')->with([
    'product' => $product,
    'mightAlsoLike' => $mightAlsoLike,
]);
```

And then just call the `$product->flavors` in the view:

```
@foreach ($product->flavors as $flavor)
  <select id="product-flavor" class="bs-select">
     <option value="{{ $flavor }}">{{ $flavor }}</option>
  </select>
@endforeach
```

The above view code would work as-is without actually calling `->with('flavors')` on the query. [`->with(...)`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) eager loads the relationship and is good practice to explicitly call when loading multiple parents, to avoid `n+1` problem (performance!).

But in your case you're only showing the flavors from 1 product, so there's no real advantage to calling it explicitly (except clearer code).

**Edit to address the  comment:**

```
<select id="product-flavor" class="bs-select">
@foreach ($product->flavors as $flavor)
    <option value="{{ $flavor->id }}">{{ $flavor->name }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

You're seeing multiple selects because you're printing the whole select inside the loop instead of just printing the options.

And to display any attribute from the current flavor, just call the attribute name: `$flavor->name` for example.

Comment: Okay, thank you!  I implemented that and it is getting somewhere, except it's displaying everything in the flavors table (id, name, created at, updated at) instead of just the name and it's also giving multiple dropdowns instead of just one dropdown with each flavor.  I will continue trying to troubleshoot, but any additional suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See the edit. Just call attributes on `$flavor` like on any other model

Comment: Okay, thank you and got that (success!).  Any idea why I'm getting a dropdown for each flavor instead of one dropdown for all flavors?  I'm assuming it's something simple...

Comment: You're iterating over the flavors associated with the current model. If you want to iterate over all of them, you'll need a separate query to get all the flavors and iterate over those

Comment: Right, but the flavors for the current model are showing up as individual dropdowns, when I just want one dropdown populated with all the flavors for the current model.  You're saying that requires a separate query?  Thank you again so much!

Comment: So you want the select to show just 1 option, but show all flavors in that 1 option? Just move the `foreach` into the `<option>` DOM. Don't really know the plugins your using or what's showing up so can't really help too much there